# Python - Is it possible to get the name of the chained function?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

I'm working on a class that basically allows for method chaining, for setting some attrbutes for different dictionaries stored.

The syntax is as follows:

```
d = Test()
d.connect().setAttrbutes(Message=Blah, Circle=True, Key=True)
```

But there can also be other instances, so, for example:

```
d = Test()
d.initialise().setAttrbutes(Message=Blah)
```

Now I believe that I can overwrite the "setattrbutes" function; I just don't want to create a function for each of the dictionary. Instead I want to capture the name of the previous chained function. So in the example above I would then be given "connect" and "initialise" so I know which dictionary to store these inside.

I hope this makes sense. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

Would this work / Be a good work-around the above problem:

Using method overloading, I can have the following methods:

```
def setAttrbutes(self, Name="Foo", Message="", Circle=False):
    print "Attrbutes method called for 'Foo'"

def setAttrbutes(self, Name="Boo", Message=""):
    print "Attrbutes method called for 'Boo'"
```

So therefore, I can say which method to call depends on the name that is used. For example, in main, if I have the following:

```
d.setAttrbutes(Name="Foo", Message="Hello world", Circle=True) # this will call the first
d.setAttrbutes(Name="Boo", Message="Hello world") # this will call the second
```

Would this work, and, if not, why?

Comment: Method chaining is an anti-pattern in Python. Functions that mutate an object idiomatically return `None`, like `list.sort`. This is intentional.

Comment: Meanwhile, why do you want to capture the name of the previous function, instead of making use of something identifiable about what each function returns?

Comment: @abarnert So could I create the function "setAttrbutes" to be able to pass a name in? I.e. `setAttrbutes(Name="Connect", Circle=False);` and in main when I call the this: `setAttrbutes(Name="Connect", Circle=True)` it knows which setAttrbutes function to call? So another example: `setAttrbutes(Name="Blah", Message="Hello world")` does this make sense?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Python knows which `setAttributes` to call based on the object you call it on. If you want to dispatch on some other argument, you will have to write that explicitly. But I don't see what that has to do with the previous method's name at all.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for your reply. Please see my updated question, that should make more sense. Thanks =)

Comment: why don't you simply return an object from `connect()`?

Comment: No, Python does not have method overloading. The second `def setAttrbutes` just replaces the first one entirely. (If you want to simulate method overloading, you can manually dispatch on the arguments from within the method body. But usually, you don't need to do anything like that; usually, having default parameter values, and a single implementation, is all you need.)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a bad idea… but it is doable, in a few different ways.

---

Most simply, you can just have each function save its name in the object, e.g.:

```
def stash_name(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._stashed_name = func.__name__
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Test(object):
    @stash_name
    def foo(self, x):
        print x
    @stash_name
    def bar(self):
        print
```

Now, after calling `d.connect()`, `d._stashed_name` will be `"connect"`.

---

At the opposite extreme, if you want to get really hacky, you can do this without any cooperation from the preceding method. Just use `sys._getframe(1)` to find your calling context, then you can examine the frame's `f_code` to see how you were called.

You can use the `dis` module to see real bytecode. But basically, it will looks like this pseudo-bytecode:

```
LOAD_NAME d
LOAD_ATTR connect
<possibly other ops to prepare arguments>
CALL_FUNCTION 1 (or any other CALL_FUNCTION_* variant)
LOAD_ATTR setAttributes
<various other ops to prepare arguments>
CALL_FUNCTION 0
```

In this case, you can either get the attribute name from the `LOAD_ATTR`, or get the *value* that was pushed and look at its `im_func.__name__`, depending which one you want.

Of course there will be other cases that don't look like this. For example, let's say I called it as `getattr(d, ''.join('con', 'next'))()` instead of `d.connect()`. Or I looked up the unbound method and built a bound method on the fly. Or… What would you want to do in each such case? If you have the answers to all such cases, then you can work out the rule that generates those answers, then figure out how to get that from the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tacked on a second, completely different, question, here's a second answer.

> Would this work / Be a good work-around the above problem:
>
> Using method overloading, I can have the following methods:

No, you can't. Python does not have method overloading. If you `def` a method with the same name as a previous method, it just replaces the first one entirely.

There are ways to simulate method overloading by dispatching on the argument values manually within the method body. For example:

```
def _setAttrbutes_impl1(self, Name, Message, Circle):
    pass

def _setAttrbutes_impl2(self, Name, Message):
    pass

def setAttrbutes(self, Name=None, Message="", Circle=None):
    if Circle is None:
        return _setAttrbutes_impl2("Boo" if Name is None else Name, Message)
    else:
        return _setAttrbutes_impl1("Foo" if Name is None else Name, Message, Circle)
```

But this is rarely useful.